# how to change the color of part of the h2 heading in html

Tags: html, fonts, colors

I have a h2 heading that says "WHO WE ARE".  I need the word "WHO" to stay white and "WE ARE" to be red.
I can't figure out how to do this.
Please help

Answer (score 7):

You normally have to (HTML)tag the part of the text you want to change the color of. And then use CSS to change the color. For example:

```css
h2 {color:red;}
h2 .colorTwo {color:blue;}
```

```html
<h2><span class="colorTwo">WHO</span> WE ARE</h2>
```

**UPDATE:** I have to improve this response since it is reaching a lot of people and I want them to start writing HTML & CSS the right way :)

That said, it is good practice to add semantics to the code you write, which is basically adding meaning to it.

So instead of using the class `colorTwo` you want to call it `emphasized` or even instead of using the `span` HTML element and a class, just use the `em` HTML element like this:

```css
h2 {color:red;}
h2 em {color:blue; font-style: normal}
```

```html
<h2><em>WHO</em> WE ARE</h2>
```

**Note:** see that I had to add `font-style: normal` to my css since the `em` HTML tag is interpreted by browsers as `font-style: italic` so I had to override it.

There is a bunch of information about the semantic web for developers. I'll leave here two links:

- https://developers.google.com/style/semantic-tagging
- https://html.com/semantic-markup/

Comment: Thanks for helping.  Much appreciated

Comment: @JoseAvila I would appreciate if you mark the answer as the correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wanna use CSS.

```html
<h2><span style='color:red'>Who</span> we are.</h2>
```